# What is $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

How to find $\operatorname{Ext}_{\mathbb{Z}} (\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$?
Thank you

Comment: Are you looking at $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ as $\mathbb{Z}$-modules?

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano:The OP are looking for the set of all equivalence classes of abelian extensions $G$ ok $\mathbb Z_n$ by $\mathbb Z_m$. But do you think the OP should consider an order between $n$ and $m$?

Comment: @GiovanniDeGaetano: Yes they are $\mathbb{Z}$-modules (see edit).

Answer (score 7):

$\bullet$ Write down a projective resolution for $\mathbb Z/m\mathbb Z$.

$\bullet$ Apply the functor $\text{Hom}(-,\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$.

$\bullet$ Take homology of the complex you obtained.

Try to work through these steps on your own. It will be very beneficial for you.